# How do I make a button pick up a function

Tags: javascript, button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function thisButtonIsDumb() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Class');
var range1 = sheet.getRange("8:8")
var class = sheet.getRange('Traits!L3').getValue();
  if (class == "Warlock") {
    sheet.getRange("10:10").setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.CLIP);
  } else {
    range1.setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.CLIP);
  }
  if (class == "Warlock") {
    sheet.setRowHeight(10,21);
  } else {
    sheet.setRowHeight(8,21)
}
}
```

Currently, thisButtonIsDumb is not picking up the script so it can;t run the script. It says "Script function thisButtonIsDumb could not be found". It is not connecting and I don't know why.

Comment: How are you assigning the `thisButtonIsDumb` to the button?

Comment: A button that you draw: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737537/7215091 an html button in a dialog or sidebar `<input type="button" value="A  Button" onClick="google.script.run.thisButtonIsDumb();" />`

Comment: @Cooper that is not compatible with the mobile version right? If not then I guess checkbox is still the closest thing to a button...

Comment: The button type is just a google drawing that is assigned a script to

Comment: @CodeCamper I don't use the mobile sheets very much.  I do all of my mobile stuff with webapps.  I don't really like to use mobile sheets as it's too easy to mess things up with my clumsy old fingers.

Comment: @Cooper If you are using webapps for everything then are you really using google sheets though? I mean can't you connect webapps to just a regular database?

Comment: @CodeCamper I prefer using Google Sheets over databases for small amounts of data. But please let's stick to the OP question and not chit chat about other issues.  If you have question then ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

To assign a script to a button you have to:

1. Right click the button
2. Assign Script

[image]

3. Set the function name without the () -> thisButtonIsDumb

[image]

See [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)

Comment: brilliant answer.